# Storing double value in the place of unsigned int

Tags: c

See these lines in the program:

```c
if (ftPtr) {
    *ftPtr = feet;
}
```

Note that `feet` contains `double` value as a result of `modf()`. On the other hand `ftPtr` is an address for an `unsigned int` variable.

**Question**
Now this program runs fine without any warning, but it leaves a bad taste in my mouth that double value is assigned to int variable. Is assigning double value to int variable using its address *kosher* in C?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void metersToFeetAndInches(double meters, unsigned int *ftPtr, double *inPtr) {
    double feet;
    double inches;

    double rawFeet = meters * 3.281;

    inches = modf(rawFeet, &feet);

    if (ftPtr) {
        *ftPtr = feet;
    }

    if (inPtr) {
        *inPtr = inches;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double meters = 1.80;
    unsigned int feet;
    double inches;

    metersToFeetAndInches(meters, &feet, &inches);
    printf("%.2f meters is %d feet and %.2f", meters, feet, inches);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is fine.

The `double` will first be converted to an `unsigned int`, and then it will be stored. It's as if you had written:

```
if (ftPtr) {
    *ftPtr = (unsigned int)feet;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pointer is just an address:

A `char pointer` can point to a block of data, which can be anything (`int`, `char`, `long`, `double`). But when you print it, you'll see only the data that can be contained in that data type.
i.e. in this case if char pointer points to `int`, then only the `1st byte` of the `int` will be printed. No harm done.

But it will be improper, not what you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a double in an unsigned int, but the sizes are not the same.
While sizeof(unsigned int) is 4 in a 32 bit system, sizeof(double) is 8. So you can store a 8 byte long value in a 4 bytes long space, but loss of data can happen (the upper 4 bites can be trimmed of the original double value).